# EXT3 JS Grid - Change a specific JsonStore Value before rendering and ordering

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to append an int to a specific cell in the grid - this needs to happen before rendering and ordering so that the user sees the correct ordering

This is for a league table.

I have bene through several iterations of conver - renderer - record.push etc
Clue seems to be to copy the store and use a new one in the grid when the value has been changed

Any help on this appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could do something similar to the following:

```
var grid, gridStore, tempStore;

gridStore = new Ext.data.Store();
tempStore = new Ext.data.Store();
grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: gridStore
});
tempStore.addListener("load", function (store, records) {
    //make your modifications to the records (concat the int)

    gridStore.loadData(/*some results*/);
});
```